# Using superscript in Android

Tags: android

Am trying to use mathematical notations in my android app.
Is there any better way to implement the power notation other than for example 2^32..?
I mean if I want to use 2 power 32 is there any superscript implementation in android sdk or should I use 2^32 itself..?
Thanks

Comment: If all you need to do is create exponents then @ArtooDetoo has the best answer.  I suggest researching `TeX`.  You'll need to find a library compatible with the Android graphics.  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41609/tex-rendering-in-a-java-application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use  Html.fromHtml to format some portions of strings in a TextView

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("2<sup>32</sup>"));
```

Will write: 2<sup>32</sup>

List of supported tags for [Html.fromHtml](http://daniel-codes.blogspot.it/2011/04/html-in-textviews.html)

Comment: Actually I need to write a sentence in Textview which will be followed by 2^32.....I mean within a Textview component I need to insert both text and the superscript thing...

Comment: SO, you'll write something like: `myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("This sentence ends with 2<sup>32</sup>"));`