# How to print the small H letter above hours?

Tags: android

How to get like this output?[image: see image]

I tried `<string name="h"><sup>H</sup></string>`

```
hour.setText(Meme.Stil_Time + Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.h)));
```

with no luck. Any help?

Comment: That has to be a custom layout.

Comment: @Machinarius that's right.. Thank you, just put your comment in the answer section to be the accepted one.

Comment: Does not this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22255231/using-superscript-in-android ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely a custom layout. A linear horizontal layout where all elements have top gravity comes to mind.

Comment: with a **android:paddingBottom="8dip"**

Comment: No, That will only work on small displays. Use layout gravity instead

Comment: another thing please.. how to do it in a String? I mean in a string like "H"

Comment: Make it simple. One textview for the hour, one for the h marker, one for the separator and so on